# How to change the variable, affected by a method, in the method?/c++ alternative to java put method

Tags: c++

I would like the method to change the variable by having the method include the variable in its code. Similar to the put method in java, I would like the variable to be affected by setting the index to a number and then rewriting the number at that index with another number.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string put(int pos, float f)
{
  a = f[pos];
  //pos - The index at which the float will be written
  //f - The float value to be written 
}

int main ()
{
  int x = 6;
  int y = 2;
  int z = 3;
  float a[100];
  a.put(10, y)
}
```

The only problem is that the put method changes only variable `a` while I would like it to change whatever variable pointing to it. So if there was a variable such as `b` and appeared in the code as `b.put(23, z)` it would rewrite whatever is at index 23 with number 3.

Comment: What is the function `addition`?

Comment: And what is `a` in `put`?

Comment: sorry meant `put` not `addition`.

Comment: Accept a slight change in calling syntax, as in `put(a, 10, y)`, then make `put` a free function taking three parameters. It's not quite clear though why you can't just write `a[10] = y;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Could you post an example of how to set up `out(a, 10, y)` in a class? Thanks!

Comment: "Free function", aka non-member function, is the opposite of "in a class". You don't have any classes in your program - in what class, exactly, do you expect `put` to be? Your question appears to be an instance of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I suggest you take a step back and explain what you are really trying to achieve, and why.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if pointers in C++ would achieve what you are attempting.

```
void put(float* a, int pos, float change){
    a[pos]=change;
}
```

Of course, you will need to be careful with accessing memory locations past the size of your array, but this put function would work for any array. However, this begs the question of what exactly you are attempting to do as it would be far more readable to change the value directly. The only "put" method I can imagine you're referring to from Java is for HashMaps, and the C++ equivalent is unordered_map. More information on that can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/).  It has an insert function which is equivalent to the Java put.

From reading the above comment, using pointers to variables instead of variables themselves would achieve what you seem to be looking for.

Comment: I am trying to make a c++ alternative to the java put method so that I could change `this.vertexBuffer.put(this.vertices * 3 + 0, x)` in java to `this->vertexBuffer.put(this->vertices * 3 + 0, x)` or `put(*vertexBuffer, this->vertices * 3 + 0, x)` in c++. I would like the put method to be in a header file and then link it to the cpp file with the coding.

Comment: Just copy the function signature in the header file, and then implement it in the cpp.

Comment: The Methods:: has nothing to do with the name of the header file, but rather the class. For example, you could name it AAAA.h and it would still work fine. Since this function is a free function, then it does not need the scope resolution operator.

Comment: While using the method above, how might I using the put method in a put method? Example: `this.vertexBuffer.put(this.vertices * 3 + 0, x).put(this.vertices * 3 + 1, y).put(this.vertices * 3 + 2, z);`

Comment: Since the put method takes the array as an argument you would have to have modify it so that it returns the array. When it returns a float* in this case, you can write something like put( put(this.vertexBuffer, this.verticies*3+0,x) , this.verticies*3+1, y) etc. At the same time, what exactly are you trying to do? Why use a put method when you can just use array access directly? If you don't like writing this.vertexBuffer constantly, you can create a pointer to that with a shorter name.

Comment: If you had arrays in Java, why was [] access not used also?

Comment: At the time it seemed more efficient to just use arrays. The java code was part of a small project I worked on a few years ago so I'm not really sure why I used some things. I am currently working to "update" the project in c++. Please keep in mind that I am trying to change the java code to c++ instead of working in java.

Comment: I think it's worth updating the put method to arr[i]=newValue directly for this updated c++ project :). The put method is much harder to reason about and understand in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Define class to create such type of function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class hoge {
private: // only for readability
  float a[100];
public:
  void put(int pos, float f)
  {
    if (pos >= 0 && pos < (int)(sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))) a[pos] = f;
    //pos - The index at which the float will be written
    //f - The float value to be written 
  }
};

int main ()
{
  int x = 6;
  int y = 2;
  int z = 3;
  hoge a;
  a.put(10, y);
}
```

Comment: Silence on invalid argument? Not a good idea. Also, see [`std::extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent).

Comment: How would you create a method so that it affect any variable that points to it and not just variable `a`?

Comment: Use pointer to the array.  And then from within that function you should be able to change any value in the array.